# Selectbox border color

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Right now i'm working with a select box for my first django-bootstrap project.
I'm trying to style it so when you click on it its border and the options box border turns yellow, and that's working fine, but there is also a blue rectangle around my selectbox when i click on it that i don't really want.

Here is my code: (Styles.css)

```
.selector{
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:1rem;
    margin-left:260px;
    width:500px;
    height:35px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align-last: center;
    color:#C9C9C9;
    transition-property: none;  
}

.selector:focus{
    border-color:#FFD700;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    border-radius:1rem;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And my HTML Template:

```
<div class="div1">  
    <label for="estado" class="label1">
        Estado
    <select class="selector" id="estado" name="estado" onchange="functionfs()" style="border-color: #C9C9C9;">
        <option style="color:#C9C9C9" selected="selected" value="-----">--- Ingrese un valor ---</option>
        <option value="Activo" style="color:black;">Activo</option>
        <option value="Inactivo" style="color:black;">Inactivo</option>
    </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Attached there is an image with more details.

Thanks to anyone willing to respond!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NckLs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) css key: `outline: none;`

```
.selector{
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:1rem;
    margin-left:260px;
    width:500px;
    height:35px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align-last: center;
    color:#C9C9C9;
    transition-property: none;
    outline: none;
}
```